# Is there a way to reformat a RAID array without losing existing data on the disks?

Tags: linux, filesystems, raid

I have a RAID 10 comprised of 4x 4TB disks. It is currently formatted in XFS on a CentOS server (The server's root directory is is not on the RAID), and I've been looking at replacing XFS with ZFS from zfsonlinux.org. However I don't have enough space elsewhere to hold my data while formatting.

Is there a way for me to reformat my RAID without losing any data? This sounds like a LMGTFY problem, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, you cannot reformat an entire RAID array without losing data.

You will need to move the data elsewhere and then reformat to your chosen file system.